# Finding the name of a wireless interface from kernel module

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I have a WiFi PCI-e card that adds two wireless interfaces to my Linux OS. I am writing a script that basically automates the initialization and configuration of this WiFi card. However, I would like to find a way to get the name of the wireless interfaces that appears in my system after loading the corresponding Linux Kernel module, i.e., this card's driver.

I came up with the following two solutions but they are still not ideal:

1. Check the Kernel log output(`dmesg | grep "driver_name"`) but I prefer another way in which I do not rely on a log file as it might get over-written.
2. Check the output of `lshw -C network` but this is a bit slow and requires a bit of parsing for the output string.

Any better solution to do this?

Comment: How about: `iwconfig` ?

Comment: Usually all this is handled by `udev` and you can add your own rules there.

Comment: @chili555 `iwconfig` does not do what I want. It just show a list of wireless interfaces but I am interested in the ones loaded by specific kernel module

Comment: @mpboden it does not show the name of the wireless interface

Comment: @Marco can you elaborate on this with any example, please?

Comment: It's quiet complex and depending on your installation. But there are plenty of examples in the web, e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev

Comment: In short, as soon as a device is detect the `udev` is triggered. Usually the rules create nodes in `/dev` or mount something etc. But scripts can be triggered, too. I think this is the right place for you to add the functionality you want. Maybe there is already a rule for your device and you just have to modify it a bit.

Comment: @mpboden the name of the wireless interface that you get in ifconfig or iwconfig e.g., wlp0s20f3.

Comment: @Marco that is not what I am looking for and I want to execute my script at a later time, not during the device boot-up. I need a simple mechanism just to let me find out what Ethernet/wireless interfaces were added to the system when a certain kernel module was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of the driver that the device will be bound to, then you can search the `/sys` filesystem and get a list of network devices that are using it.

If you don't know the name of the driver just yet, you can find it first with: `lspci -nnk | grep -i 'network\|ethernet' -A3`.

### Example 1

**Let's find the drivers:**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i 'network\|ethernet' -A3
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d3]
        Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [15d9:10d3]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d3]
        Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [15d9:10d3]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
08:08.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas Instruments TSB43AB22A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [iOHCI-Lynx] [104c:8023]
```

Notice that is says *Kernel driver in use: e1000e*. That's the driver my network cards are using. For your system, substitute your driver name in place of *e1000e* in the following example.

Now that we know the driver in use, *e1000e*, I can search the `/sys` filesystem and find which network devices are using this driver with the following command:

```
$ find -L /sys/class/net -maxdepth 3 -name "uevent" -exec grep -iH "e1000e" {} \; 2> /dev/null
/sys/class/net/eth0/device/uevent:DRIVER=e1000e
/sys/class/net/eth1/device/uevent:DRIVER=e1000e
```

From there, I can use `awk` to get the network device names:

```
$ find -L /sys/class/net -maxdepth 3 -name "uevent" -exec grep -iH "e1000e" {} \; 2> /dev/null | awk -F / '{print $5}'
eth0
eth1
```

### Example 2

As another example on a different computer, I have both WIFI and an ethernet controller, each with a different driver.

**Let's find the drivers:**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i 'network\|ethernet' -A3
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0020]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
--
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15f2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22d8]
    Kernel driver in use: igc
    Kernel modules: igc
```

**WIFI with the *iwlwifi* driver:**

```
$ find -L /sys/class/net -maxdepth 3 -name "uevent" -exec grep -iH "iwlwifi" {} \; 2> /dev/null
/sys/class/net/wlp9s0/device/uevent:DRIVER=iwlwifi

$ find -L /sys/class/net -maxdepth 3 -name "uevent" -exec grep -iH "iwlwifi" {} \; 2> /dev/null | awk -F / '{print $5}'
wlp9s0
```

**Ethernet Controller with the *igc* driver:**

```
$ find -L /sys/class/net -maxdepth 3 -name "uevent" -exec grep -iH "igc" {} \; 2> /dev/null
/sys/class/net/enp11s0/device/uevent:DRIVER=igc

$ find -L /sys/class/net -maxdepth 3 -name "uevent" -exec grep -iH "igc" {} \; 2> /dev/null | awk -F / '{print $5}'
enp11s0
```